# Piece missing in Error bar

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot an error bar using a graphic element as a symbol.
However, the error bar that I get misses a piece (the vertical part).
How can this be fixed?

thanks

```
disR = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Black]], 
    Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 18];
L = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[3], Black, Line[{{0, 0}, {0.2, 0}}]}];

ListPlot[{{{0, 48.72008467928146`}}, {{0, 42.94658198738521`}}, {{0, 
    45.833333333333336`}}},
 PlotMarkers -> {L, L, disR},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3], Opacity[1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can format your code with the `{}` button

Comment: Why would you expect it to be there? you haven't defined it in anyway. Why are you using custom errorbars anyway? Look at `ErrorListPlot[]`

Comment: It is just the way I want to have the symbol with error bar. I tried to put it there with Filling. Hence, I did not need to define it.

Answer (score 3):

The base issue seems to be that `Filling` in a `ListPlot` will only work when the individual lists have more than one element

```
Function[{n}, list1 = {#, #} & /@ Range[n];
  list2 = {#, Prime@#} & /@ Range[n];
  ListPlot[{list1, list2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
  ] /@ {1, 2}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've reported this as a bug.  I don't think you can get this via `Filling`, but you can use a workaround,

```
{list1, list2, 
   list3} = {{{0, 48.72008467928146}}, {{0, 42.94658198738521}}, {{0, 
     45.833333333333336`}}};
ListPlot[{list1, list2, list3}, PlotMarkers -> {L, L, disR}, 
 Epilog -> {Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3], Opacity[1]], 
   Line @@ Thread[{list1, list2}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you can use `Prolog` instead of `Epilog` to get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to do this for some data, where I assume you have it in the form of 3 lists - one for the values, and one each for the values $\pm$ the error, then you could extend this idea like

```
(* Make some plausible looking fake data *)
```

(* Make some plausible looking fake data *)

```
xvals = Sort[RandomSample[Range[0, 20, .5], 20]];
vals = {#, 20 Sin[#/\[Pi]] + RandomReal[0.5]} & /@ xvals;
errors = RandomReal[{5, 8}, Length@vals];
{bottom, top} =
  {Thread[{xvals, vals[[All, 2]] + errors/2}],
   Thread[{xvals, vals[[All, 2]] - errors/2}]};
(*Then make your home-made error bar plot *)

ListPlot[{top, bottom, vals},
 PlotMarkers -> {L, L, disR},
 Prolog -> {Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3], Opacity[1]],
   Line /@ Thread[{top, bottom}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can achieve similar results using `ErrorListPlot`, but in my opinion that package is due for an update.  I had to fiddle with the settings quite a bit to figure out the syntax,

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
ErrorListPlot[
 Thread[{vals, ErrorBar /@ (errors/2)}],
 PlotMarkers -> disR,
 ErrorBarFunction -> Function[{point, err},
   {Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3], Opacity[1]],
    Line[{point + {0, err[[2, 1]]}, point + {0, err[[2, 2]]}}],
    Line[{point + {-.2, err[[2, 1]]}, point + {.2, err[[2, 1]]}}],
    Line[{point + {-.2, err[[2, 2]]}, point + {.2, err[[2, 2]]}}]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks. this works. however one needs to re-write list1 and list2 in Epilog. (Line @@ Thread[{list1, list2}]). I suppose this can be automated. But how?

Comment: @Luigi - see the edit.  As for automating, if you are going to do something more than once, make it a function, like `errorPlot[top_, bottom_, vals_] := 
 ListPlot[{top, bottom, vals}, PlotMarkers -> {L, L, disR}, 
  Prolog -> {Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3], Opacity[1]], 
    Line /@ Thread[{top, bottom}]}]`